# EditText almost invisible after virtual keyboard appears

Tags: android

As shown in both screenshots, I have 3 editTexts in an Activity layout.
When I touch the first one (Message1), the virtual keyboard appears as one should expect.
Nevertheless, that first editText seems almost invisible now.

Here is my layout xml :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.n.MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </View>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Message1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </View>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Message2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </View>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="sw"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >
            </View>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/d"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
                android:text="d"
                android:drawablePadding="10dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" >
            </View>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Please help to solve this bad UI behaviour.

Regards,

PS : Don't let the virtual keyboard ios's custom design mislead you. We are talking here of Android and the issue was happening even before the customization.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the concerned activity under your manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```